Automorphism group of d-regular trees
A (infinite) tree is $d$-regular if every vertex has $d$-many neighbors. Needless to say, the tree will be infinite in size. My question is about the automorphism group of the said tree, $\mathrm{Aut(T_d)}$, and its size. I want to show that $\mathrm{Aut(T_d)}$ has continuum cardinality.
My aim is to encode automorphisms as infinite $d$-nary sequences and show that the corresponding map is surjective. This will guarantee that $|\mathrm{Aut(T_d)}|\geq |\mathbb{R}|$. Next, I want to find an injective map from automorphism group of $T_d$ to the set of infinite $d$-nary sequences, which will hopefully finish the proof.
One idea is to fix a root of the tree. Automorphisms of graphs preserve distances. That is: fixing a root $x$ in our tree, let $D_i$ be the set of vertices that are distance $i$ away from $x$. Any automorphism of $T_d$ must be distance preserving permutation of the vertices in $D_i$. At every level, we consider the possible permutations of the infinite subtrees. Meaning: that whenever we permute vertices in $D_i$, we 'switch' the sub-tree arising from the vertex. Next, for each of the branches on the given sub-tree, we have $d$ many options. As a result, we get a sequence of arrangements, each of which represents some automorphism.
I don't know where to go from here or how to formalize this into a rigorous proof.

First, we can get an easy upper bound $|\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}|=|\mathbb R|$. This is just counting all functions $V(T_d)\to V(T_d)$.
To get a lower bound, we don't need to consider anywhere near the total number of automorphisms. We give an injection $f$ from countable $(d-2)$-nary sequences to $\text{Aut}(T_d)$. Consider a particular vertex $v_0$, and form an infinite path $(v_0,v_1,v_2,\ldots)$. For each $i\in \mathbb N$, enumerate $N(v_{i-1})=\{v_{i-2},v_{i},u_i^1,u_i^2,\ldots, u_i^{d-2}\}$ (with the exception of $v_0$). For each $(d-2)$-nary sequence $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ we define the automorphism $\sigma(x)$ in the following way: For each $i\in \{1,2,\ldots,\infty\}$: swap $v_i$ (and its entire branch) with $u_i^{x_i}$. Then look at the neighborhood of $v_i$ and repeat for $i+1$.
This process forms a unique automorphism, so it is a valid injection $\sigma:(d-2)^{\mathbb N}\to \text{Aut}(T_d)$. Notice that we didn't even need $(d-2)$-nary sequences in general; it would have been enough to use binary sequences and form a simpler injection. We conclude $|\text{Aut}(T_d)|=|\mathbb R|$.

What's $d_i^{x_i}$?

Small note: the lower bound does not work for $d = 3$. In this case you might argue: pick an arbitrary root, and forget one of its neighbors. Then you are left with an infinite binary tree, which you can see as the set of finite binary sequences, where the parent of a node $s$ is given by $s$ without its final digit. Then you can encode an infinite binary sequence $x$ by the mapping that sends $s$ to the bitwise xor of $s$ and the first $|s|$ digits of $x$.

This proof would work for d=3 if we also let $v_i=u_i^{d-1}$. This way there would still be $d-1$ options for each step instead of $d-2$ (one option would be to swap $v_i$ with itself)
